# Update previous rows based on another row

Tags: sql-server

I have a question and i need to update the empty rows based on the rows with value

[image]

In this case, i need to update the hours, mins and secs based on every 4th row
For ex: rownum 4 has 8hours, 1mins, 9 sec.

So, my update to previous row should be 8hrs, 1min, 6 sec from rownum 1, then, for rownum 5 it should continue the same procedure

See rownum 8 has 8hours, 1mins, 13 sec.

The previous 3 rows should be 8hrs, 1min, 10 sec from rownum 5
How to have this in a loop or with partition by or any suggestion in SQL server.

Comment: Images of such a large amount of data don't help us help you. Take the time to post your data in a **consumable** format (preferable DDL and DML statements) along with your expected results for said data. Also,explain the problem in full, as you aren't particularly clear on what the logic is here.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind what you are doing, please elaborate

Comment: This excel data has been loaded into sql table.

Comment: IF you the excel, every 4th row has hour, min and sec values. But , other rows dont have those values.  Need to update in table based on every 4th row in the table.

Comment: Take the time to provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), I doubt anyone is going to do your work for you and type all that in.

Comment: My row has rownum which is from 1 to n. I have hours , min and secs in every 4th row. The other top 3 rows will have to calculate the hours , min and sec based on every 4th row. Lets say 4th row has 8 in hours, 1 in min and 9 in sec column. The top rows should have to calculate the hours , min and sec based on the 4th row. Similarly, 8th row will have 8 in hours, 1 in min and 13 in sec column. So, rownum 5th to 7th should calculate hour , min and sec based on 8th row. Expected result will be 8 hour, 1 min and 10 sec in 5th row. For 6th row, 8 hour, 1min and 11 sec in the corresponding columns

Comment: Does this help - [How to select the set of last non-NULL values per column over a group?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208935/how-to-select-the-set-of-last-non-null-values-per-column-over-a-group)

Comment: But my requirement is to have hours , min and sec based on every 4th row hours, min and sec column

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions and converting your hours, minutes and seconds to a `time` value. Converting to a `tim` is important to make sure you wrap around the appropriate time boundaries and don't end up with `61` seconds in a minute etc.

Depending on the data and your real world environment you will probably need to add the `Flight` and maybe some other columns into the `partition by`s to ensure you are working correctly scoped windows of data.

## Query

```
declare @t table(rn int,timeframe int,h int,m int,s int);
insert into @t values
 (1,1,null,null,null)
,(2,1,null,null,null)
,(3,1,null,null,null)
,(4,1,23,59,45)
,(5,2,null,null,null)
,(6,2,null,null,null)
,(7,2,null,null,null)
,(8,2,23,59,49)
,(9,3,null,null,null)
,(10,3,null,null,null)
,(11,3,null,null,null)
,(12,3,23,59,53)
,(13,4,null,null,null)
,(14,4,null,null,null)
,(15,4,null,null,null)
,(16,4,23,59,57)
,(17,5,null,null,null)
,(18,5,null,null,null)
,(19,5,null,null,null)
,(20,5,0,0,1)
,(21,6,null,null,null)
,(22,6,null,null,null)
,(23,6,null,null,null)
,(24,6,0,0,5)
;

with d as
(
    select rn
          ,timeframe
          ,dateadd(second
                  ,rn - max(rn) over (partition by timeframe)
                  ,max(timefromparts(h,m,s,0,0)) over (partition by timeframe)
                  ) as t
    from @t
)
select rn
      ,timeframe
      ,datepart(hour,t) as h
      ,datepart(minute,t) as m
      ,datepart(second,t) as s
from d
order by rn;
```

---

## Output

| rn | timeframe | h | m | s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23 | 59 | 42 |
| 2 | 1 | 23 | 59 | 43 |
| 3 | 1 | 23 | 59 | 44 |
| 4 | 1 | 23 | 59 | 45 |
| 5 | 2 | 23 | 59 | 46 |
| 6 | 2 | 23 | 59 | 47 |
| 7 | 2 | 23 | 59 | 48 |
| 8 | 2 | 23 | 59 | 49 |
| 9 | 3 | 23 | 59 | 50 |
| 10 | 3 | 23 | 59 | 51 |
| 11 | 3 | 23 | 59 | 52 |
| 12 | 3 | 23 | 59 | 53 |
| 13 | 4 | 23 | 59 | 54 |
| 14 | 4 | 23 | 59 | 55 |
| 15 | 4 | 23 | 59 | 56 |
| 16 | 4 | 23 | 59 | 57 |
| 17 | 5 | 23 | 59 | 58 |
| 18 | 5 | 23 | 59 | 59 |
| 19 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 21 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 22 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 23 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 24 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Comment: Hi, This is really what i was looking for. Also, will you be able to advise how to dynamically update date based on this time. Lets say, my row 1 starts with 06 , jun, 2020. I want to update the rest of the rows based on the time

Comment: Just use `datetimefromparts` instead of `timefromparts` and use the other values within your table to fill in the extra parts of the `datetime`.